# Codeigniter 4: Unable to modify database credentials on production

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-4

I changed my database username for production from fpodev to newone

```
public $default = [
    'DSN'      => '',
    'hostname' => 'localhost',
    'username' => 'newuser',
    'password' => 'newpass',
    'database' => 'devapp_fpo',
    'DBDriver' => 'MySQLi',
    'DBPrefix' => '',
    'pConnect' => false,
    'DBDebug'  => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
    'cacheOn'  => false,
    'cacheDir' => '',
    'charset'  => 'utf8',
    'DBCollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swapPre'  => '',
    'encrypt'  => false,
    'compress' => false,
    'strictOn' => false,
    'failover' => [],
    'port'     => 3306,
];
```

Saved it and tried to hit the api [(Link](http://3.143.153.117/fpo_server/api/get-all-counts)) [POST] but I get the following response

```
{
"title": "mysqli_sql_exception",
"type": "mysqli_sql_exception",
"code": 500,
"message": "The user specified as a definer ('fpodev'@'localhost') does not exist",
"file": "/var/www/html/fpo_server/vendor/codeigniter4/framework/system/Database/MySQLi/Connection.php",
"line": 329,
"trace": [
    {
        "file": "/var/www/html/fpo_server/vendor/codeigniter4/framework/system/Database/MySQLi/Connection.php",
        "line": 329,
        "function": "query",
        "class": "mysqli",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "/var/www/html/fpo_server/vendor/codeigniter4/framework/system/Database/BaseConnection.php",
        "line": 732,
        "function": "execute",
        "class": "CodeIgniter\\Database\\MySQLi\\Connection",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "/var/www/html/fpo_server/vendor/codeigniter4/framework/system/Database/BaseConnection.php",
        "line": 647,
        "function": "simpleQuery",
        "class": "CodeIgniter\\Database\\BaseConnection",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "/var/www/html/fpo_server/app/Models/FPO.php",
        "line": 442,
        "function": "query",
        "class": "CodeIgniter\\Database\\BaseConnection",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "/var/www/html/fpo_server/app/Controllers/FPOController.php",
        "line": 674,
        "function": "fpo_search_count",
        "class": "App\\Models\\FPO",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "/var/www/html/fpo_server/vendor/codeigniter4/framework/system/CodeIgniter.php",
        "line": 931,
        "function": "get_all_counts",
        "class": "App\\Controllers\\FPOController",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "/var/www/html/fpo_server/vendor/codeigniter4/framework/system/CodeIgniter.php",
        "line": 439,
        "function": "runController",
        "class": "CodeIgniter\\CodeIgniter",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "/var/www/html/fpo_server/vendor/codeigniter4/framework/system/CodeIgniter.php",
        "line": 339,
        "function": "handleRequest",
        "class": "CodeIgniter\\CodeIgniter",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "/var/www/html/fpo_server/index.php",
        "line": 45,
        "function": "run",
        "class": "CodeIgniter\\CodeIgniter",
        "type": "->"
    }
 ]
}
```

In Laravel we have commands like

php artisan db:clear cache:clear route:clear etc.

What do we do in Codeigniter 4

Comment: I don't think you need to clear the Database cache or anything. Usually, any changes in live reflects instantly. Can you confirm if you have .env file with database configurations? If that's the case then it will be one overriding your configurations.

Comment: The error message: The user specified as a definer ('fpodev'@'localhost') does not exist", would be a good place to start.

Comment: Ok I found the issue,, apparently my password had a special character which I didn't know of. got strangled for 2 days.